# How do I remove the expressapp logo from xaf web application

Tags: devexpress, graphical-logo, xaf

I've created a XAF web application. However, each time I run it and log in, the following icon is shown in the top left corner of the web page
[image]

how do I remove it or replace it with my own logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [How to: Apply a Client's Logo to XAF Applications](http://help.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument3156) topic.